# I got a error while trying to read a text file

Tags: vb.net

Screenshot with the error:

[image]

The actual error message:

> ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

I learned something on stackoverflow, and when i used it it worked, but when i used it in another project i got this.

Here is the code in case you want to copy it and test it.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path_proporties_file) Then
        Dim lstSettings As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        'Loop through each line.
        For Each strLine As String In IO.File.ReadAllLines(path_proporties_file)

            'Ignore empty lines and comments.
            If strLine.Length > 0 AndAlso strLine.Substring(0, 1) <> "#" Then

                'Split the Key from the Value.
                Dim LstKeyValue As List(Of String) = strLine.Split("=").ToList()

                'Some additional filtering of bad data.
                If LstKeyValue.Count = 2 Then

                    'Add to the Dictionary instance.
                    lstSettings.Add(LstKeyValue(0), LstKeyValue(1))

                End If

            End If

        Next

        Dim item_1_name = CStr(lstSettings("item_1_name"))
        Dim item_1_path = CStr(lstSettings("item_1_path"))
        Dim item_1_enabled = CBool(lstSettings("item_1_enabled"))

        Dim item_2_name = CStr(lstSettings("item_2_name"))
        Dim item_2_path = CStr(lstSettings("item_2_path"))
        Dim item_2_enabled = CBool(lstSettings("item_2_enabled"))

        Dim item_3_name = CStr(lstSettings("item_3_name"))
        Dim item_3_path = CStr(lstSettings("item_3_path"))
        Dim item_3_enabled = CBool(lstSettings("item_3_enabled"))

        Dim item_4_name = CStr(lstSettings("item_4_name"))
        Dim item_4_path = CStr(lstSettings("item_4_path"))
        Dim item_4_enabled = CBool(lstSettings("item_4_enabled"))

        Dim item_5_name = CStr(lstSettings("item_5_name"))
        Dim item_5_path = CStr(lstSettings("item_5_path"))
        Dim item_5_enabled = CBool(lstSettings("item_5_enabled"))

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Proporties file cannot be found")
    End If
End Sub
```

Sorry if its a dumb question, but i looked it up and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Dictionaries must have unique keys. Your text file must have duplicate keys in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message in the error that you got is pretty clear:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

And this behavior is clearly documented for [Dictionary.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k(v=vs.110).aspx).

So when you do:

```
lstSettings.Add(LstKeyValue(0), LstKeyValue(1))
```

... the statement will throw this exception if the `lstSettings` dictionary already has the `LstKeyValue(0)` value.  It won't let you add the same key value twice.

So, apparently, your properties file has duplicate keys somewhere.  You'll have to determine how you want to deal with this case.

Comment: but how to do i prevent this error, its used like a refresh button so, in theory you could press the button multiple times within the software, can i add more keys?

Comment: Hard to give you an appropriate answer without truly understanding your program. And you say it's used like a refresh button, but the code is in the form load, so I don't quite get that.  The fact that you ask if you can add more keys makes me wonder if you understand how dictionaries work.  Maybe the best thing to do is to take a step back and do some reading on hash tables and how they work.

Comment: Actually, I just peeked at your last Q&A, and it's clear that you just copied the above code from an answer that was given to you, but you probably don't understand the code at all.  I strongly urge you to stop coding that way.  Don't take shortcuts.  Take the time to learn instead of copy pasting code from other people and hope that it works for you.

Comment: i know what the code means, but when the program created the file and i start it back up it gives this error, trying to read the file.

Comment: Well, something is off.  If the file was created from the dictionary, the file should not contain any duplicate keys, because dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.  Have you verified if the file has duplicate keys?  And if yes, then you'll have to debug how they got there in the first place.

Comment: I created it with the StreamWriter
and then:
streamwriter.writeline("thelineoftext")

Comment: @Wietse292akaSnAKE : If you want to prevent the error just put the Add-method inside an if statement: `If lstSettings.ContainsKey(LstKeyValue(0)) = False Then ...`. And since you always declare a new Dictionary every time, you do not need to worry about multiples.

Comment: @Visual: Careful with that advice.  Based on what OP is saying, I don't think the file is supposed to have duplicates.  Making that change would only mask the problem further.  OP needs to investigate what is wrong with the file, not just blindly patch the error message.

Comment: @sstan: Well it does indeed depend on what's written in the file. But as we do not know that, I gave that advice as a possibility. But yes, it's up to the OP to investigate why there are multiple entries with the same name.